# Spring Boot with Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-boot, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am using Spring Boot with Objectify for persistence layer. It is being deployed to Flexible App Engine.
In every entity I have a block:

```
static {
    ObjectifyService.register(LsUser.class); 
}
```

While trying to run this code from Controller class:

```
ObjectifyService.run(new VoidWork() {   
    @Override           
    public void vrun() {
        ofy.save().entity(new User())).now();           
    }       
});
```

When running it I have next error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: No API environment is registered for this thread.
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppId(DatastoreApiHelper.java:180) ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.30.jar:na]
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.getCurrentAppIdNamespace(DatastoreApiHelper.java:196) ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.30.jar:na]
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key.<init>(Key.java:96) ~[appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.30.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objectify is available only on App Engine standard environment and App Engine flexible environment (compat) which is currently deprecated. You should use gcloud-java instead.

[Using Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-datastore)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to deploy in GAE use [objectify-appengine-spring](https://github.com/Shilendra/objectify-appengine-spring)